# Disable Read repairs in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

We are using Apache Cassandra 3.11.4 . since  read_repair_chance/dclocal_read_repair_chance are removed.I see consistantly ERROR on read repair messages. How do we disable read repair in cassandra

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13910

```
ERROR [ReadRepairStage:5656] 2019-07-22 16:20:31,818 CassandraDaemon.java:228 - Exception in thread Thread[ReadRepairStage:5656,5,main]
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 1 responses.
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.DataResolver$RepairMergeListener.close(DataResolver.java:202) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.UnfilteredPartitionIterators$2.close(UnfilteredPartitionIterators.java:175) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.transform.BaseIterator.close(BaseIterator.java:92) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.DataResolver.compareResponses(DataResolver.java:79) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.AsyncRepairCallback$1.runMayThrow(AsyncRepairCallback.java:50) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.NamedThreadFactory.lambda$threadLocalDeallocator$0(NamedThreadFactory.java:81) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.3.jar:3.11.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
```

Comment: Can you put one of the errors into description? Read repair happens even without these 2 settings

Comment: Updated the error logs

Comment: Are all the nodes shown as UN in the nodetool status?

Comment: Yeah all the nodes are UN but because of this error mutations gets piled up and start increasing in pending state and node goes down

Comment: Possible duplicate of [timeouts on ReadRepairStage error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57099697/timeouts-on-readrepairstage-error-messages)